# In the memory puzzle game on pygame, can I keep the original reveal speed to be slow and then make it faster when playing the game?

Tags: python, pygame

This is the game code

https://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter3.html

I currently have the reveal speed set at 1, however this is for the initial reveal and the reveals while playing the game. Is there anyway that I am able to keep that initial reveal speed at 1, but then change the reveal speed while playing to something quicker?

In order to do this I feel that I would need to add a line of code under the revealspeed on line 12, I just don't know what the new line should say.

```
FPS = 30 # frames per second, the general speed of the program
WINDOWWIDTH = 640 # size of window's width in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # size of windows' height in pixels
REVEALSPEED = 2 # speed boxes' sliding reveals and covers
BOXSIZE = 60 # size of box height & width in pixels
GAPSIZE = 10 # size of gap between boxes in pixels
BOARDWIDTH = 8 # number of columns of icons
BOARDHEIGHT = 7 # number of rows of icons
assert (BOARDWIDTH * BOARDHEIGHT) % 2 == 0, 'Board needs to have an even number of boxes for pairs of matches.'
XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (BOARDWIDTH * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE))) / 2)
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (BOARDHEIGHT * (BOXSIZE + GAPSIZE))) / 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

So we want to do the animation with two different speeds, so let's create a new global variable for that first:

```
...
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # size of windows' height in pixels
# ADD THIS
INITIALREVEALSPEED = 1 # speed boxes' sliding reveals and covers AT THE START OF THE GAME
REVEALSPEED = 8 # speed boxes' sliding reveals and covers
BOXSIZE = 40 # size of box height & width in pixels
...
```

By searching for `REVEALSPEED` we see that the animation is handled in the `revealBoxesAnimation` and `coverBoxesAnimation` functions. They use the `REVEALSPEED` constant (not really constant, but hey), but we want the speed to be dynamic, so let's just pass the speed we want to use as a parameter. Change the functions to:

```
def revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxesToReveal, speed=REVEALSPEED):
    # Do the "box reveal" animation.
    for coverage in range(BOXSIZE, (-speed) - 1, -speed):
        drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToReveal, coverage)


def coverBoxesAnimation(board, boxesToCover, speed=REVEALSPEED):
    # Do the "box cover" animation.
    for coverage in range(0, BOXSIZE + speed, speed):
        drawBoxCovers(board, boxesToCover, coverage)
```

We still use `REVEALSPEED` as a default value, so we don't have to change each method call.

Since we want to only slow down the animation at the start of the game, we only have to change the method invocations that happens at the start. If we search for places where `revealBoxesAnimation` is used, we find the `startGameAnimation` function. Let's change it to:

```
def startGameAnimation(board):
    # Randomly reveal the boxes 8 at a time.
    coveredBoxes = generateRevealedBoxesData(False)
    boxes = []
    for x in range(BOARDWIDTH):
        for y in range(BOARDHEIGHT):
            boxes.append( (x, y) )
    random.shuffle(boxes)
    boxGroups = splitIntoGroupsOf(8, boxes)

    drawBoard(board, coveredBoxes)
    for boxGroup in boxGroups:
        revealBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroup, INITIALREVEALSPEED)
        coverBoxesAnimation(board, boxGroup, INITIALREVEALSPEED)
```

And that's it.